# Minimiziation over subset of $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

> Let $g\in C([0,1])$ be arbitrary. Does $\min_{f\in A}{||f-g||_\infty}$ have a solution for
>
> i) $A=\{f\in C([0,1]) : ||f||_\infty \le 1\}$
>
> ii) $A=\{f\in C([0,1]) : \int_0^1 f(x)x^2dx=0\}$

My first idea was to use the fact that the minimizer exists in a compact subset. But $A$, i.e. the closed unit ball of $C([0,1])$ from i) is not compact. For ii) I don't see how $A$ could be compact either.

Intuitively for i), I think the minimizer should be $f(x)=1$ if $|g(x)|>1$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ otherwise. I don't see how to prove it though. For ii) I have no intuition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For i) your intuition is (almost) correct.
Namely, given $g\in C([0,1])$ you can consider the truncated function
$$
g_1(x) := \max\{-1, \min\{g(x), 1\}\}
$$
so that $|g_1(x)| \leq 1$ for every $x\in [0,1]$ and $g_1(x) = g(x)$ if $|g(x)| \leq 1$.

Then you can easily verify that, for every $f\in A$,
$$
|g(x) - g_1(x)| \leq |g(x) - f(x)|,
\qquad \forall x\in [0,1].
$$
Indeed, if $|g(x)| \leq 1$, then the l.h.s. vanishes, whereas if $g(x) > 1$ or $g(x) < -1$ the inequality is easily verified taking into account that $|f(x)|\leq 1$.

For ii), given $g$ you can consider the function
$$
g_1(x) := g(x) - c,
\qquad c:= 3\int_0^1 g(t) t^2\, dt.
$$
It is easily verified that $g_1 \in A$.

W.l.o.g. assume that $c > 0$, and consider a function $f\in A$ such that
$$
\|g - f\|_\infty \leq \|g - g_1\|_\infty = c.
$$
In particular, we have that, for every $x\in [0,1]$,
$$
c \geq g(x) - f(x) = g(x) - g_1(x) + g_1(x) - f(x) = c + g_1(x) - f(x),
$$
i.e.
$g_1(x) - f(x) \leq 0$.
But $\int_0^1 [g_1(x) - f(x)]x^2\, dx = 0$, so that we necessarily have
$g_1(x) = f(x)$ for every $x\in [0,1]$.
In conclusion, $g_1$ attains the minimum.

Comment: Thank you! How does one see that one should consider $g_1$ in ii) in this fashion? It seems a bit out of the blue for me.

Comment: Truncations (in presence of obstacles) or translations by a constant are often used when minimizing a $L^\infty$ norm.

Comment: I think I see where you get the constant from: by Hölder: $\|x^2(f-g)\|_{L^1} \le \|f-g\|_{L^\infty} \|x^2\|_{L^1}$ and calculating gives $\|f-g\|_{L^\infty}\ge 3\int_0^1 g(x)x^2dx$.

Comment: The constant is given by the condition $\int_0^1 [g(x) - c]x^2\, dx = 0$.